# Linux module makefile compilation error

Tags: linux, makefile, kbuild

I have the following makefile:

```
1 MODULES_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)
2 KERNEL_DIR := ${MODULES_DIR}/build
3 
4 obj-m += module.o
5 
6 all:
7         make −C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules;
8 clean:
9         make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) clean;
```

I get the following error when invoking make:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `−C'.  Stop.
```

Does anyobody know why? I'm new. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the dash in the `-C` is a normal dash character (ASCII code 45)?  It looks to me like you may have added some fancy unicode or UTF hyphen character instead.

Comment: You are right, thanks! I pasted the −C  from somewhere and it wasn't a normal dash. :)

Comment: If this solves your problem please mark the question as answered so it shows up that way for people looking.